# Fingerprint activation in Dell Vostro 14 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, fingerprint-reader

I have Dell Vostro 14 with OS Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried

```
sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd
```

but not able to use fingerprint reader of my laptop.

Comment: Have you checked whether your device is supported?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the device is supported, according to [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-fingerprint.html.en).

Open the Activities overview and start typing Users.

Click on Users to open the panel.

Press on Disabled, next to Fingerprint Login to add a fingerprint for the selected account. If you are adding the fingerprint for a different user, you will first need to Unlock the panel.

Select the finger that you want to use for the fingerprint, then Next.

Follow the instructions in the dialog and swipe your finger at a moderate speed over your fingerprint reader. Once the computer has a good record of your fingerprint, you will see a Done! message.

Select Next. You will see a confirmation message that your fingerprint was saved successfully. Select Close to finish.