# Enable fingerprint reader login in 18.04 w/ Unity

Tags: 18.04, unity, login, fingerprint-reader

I have a Dell laptop with fingerprint reader built in. I just ran [lsusb](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/USB) with  the following result:

> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>
> Bus 001 Device 006: ID 138a:00a6 Validity Sensors, Inc.
>
> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e009 Atheros Communications, Inc.
>
> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
>
> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5689 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
>
> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:00ac Lite-On Technology Corp.
>
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Is it possible to use fingerprint scanning instead of traditional login with 18.04 and Unity ?

Comment: Please don't make multiple posts about the same problem, e.g., https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149137/fingerprint-activation-in-dell-vestro-14-in-ubuntu-18-04 Instead, in the original post, click [edit] and enhance or revise the original.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-fingerprint.html.en).

Open the Activities overview and start typing Users.

Click on Users to open the panel.

Press on Disabled, next to Fingerprint Login to add a fingerprint for the selected account. If you are adding the fingerprint for a different user, you will first need to Unlock the panel.

Select the finger that you want to use for the fingerprint, then Next.

Follow the instructions in the dialog and swipe your finger at a moderate speed over your fingerprint reader. Once the computer has a good record of your fingerprint, you will see a Done! message.

Select Next. You will see a confirmation message that your fingerprint was saved successfully. Select Close to finish.

Comment: this does *not* work under unity for the record

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/872175/using-fingerprint-reader-in-16-04 work for you?

Comment: sadly no, i'm on ubuntu 18.04 using the unity shell on a lenovo thinkpad t580

Comment: Since this is a closed post, I would suggest you create a new post, point to this post and the post I cited in the comment above, and state "This answer did not work; please do not close this as a duplicate." Please also include the results of running lsusb in your query.

Comment: btw i commented because the op was also trying to get his finger print scanner to work with the unity shell under ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Yes, but closed-as-duplicate posts may be deleted.

Comment: i don't believe it is a duplicate post as the answer in the "duplicate" works for gnome while the question is about unity

Comment: The 'community member' has veto power over all posts. Discuss with them, not me.